# Private static fields in non static class

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I have the following class:

```
class Application
{
    private Process _process; 

    private static string _applicationPath = string.Empty;

    public void Start(string arguments)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(_applicationPath))
            Deploy();
        _process = Process.Start(_applicationPath, arguments);
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        //method that manipulate _process
    }

    private void Deploy()
    {
        // copying, installation steps (takes some time) and assign _applicationPath
    }
}
```

1. Is it bad to use a static field here? I expect that other instances of `Application` will use the same `_applicationPath`.
2. Is this an example of a violation of the SRP-principle (SOLID)? Should I extract "deployment responsibility" to another class?

Comment: _It's bad that I'm using a static field?_ nope. you are using it with correct reason if other instances of SomeApplication will use the same _someApplicationPath.

Comment: This question should actually go to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @t3chb0t Nope, this is asking for explanations. We do reviews, not explanations at Code **Review**.

Comment: @t3chb0t not in its current from. That would be closed as example code.

Comment: I don't think it's asking for a code explanation, but it is defnitely example/hypothetical/design, which would be Off-Topic on CR.

Comment: This is a half review half question :) The OP asks whether this design is ok or not and why or how it works: _It's bad that I'm using a static field?_ = review;  _Is this an example of violation of SRP-principle (SOLID)_ = review, programming

Answer (score 2):

> It's bad that I'm using a static field?

It depends on what you're using it *for*.  In this case since you *change* it with a non-static method (`Deploy()`), then yes, it's probably bad.  If it should be the same for all instances, then set it in a static constructor or property (assuming that the application configuration will set it).

> Is this an example of violation of SRP-principle (SOLID)?

What are the responsibilities of this class?  Can you extract `Deploy` and `Start` logically or does one *require* the other?

Answer (score 0):

> It's bad that I'm using a static field? Expected that other instances of Application will use the same _applicationPath.

I don't think it's bad. As long as this field is private you can use it however you want. Just be careful to not change it after you've set it on deployment.

> Is this an example of violation of SRP-principle (SOLID)? And I should extract "deployment reponsibility" to other class?

Yes, I would defininetly refactor it and separate the deployment from running the application. Currently you class does more then one thing, it runs the process and deploys the app:

```
class Application
{
    private Process _process; 

    private static string _applicationPath;

    public void Start(string arguments)
    {
        var isDeployed = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_applicationPath);
        if (!isDeployed)
        {
            var deployment = new Deployment();
            _applicationPath = deployment.Deploy();
        }
        _process = Process.Start(_applicationPath, arguments);
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        //method that manipulate _process
    }    
}

class Deployment
{
    private static string _applicationPath;

    public string Deploy()
    {
        if (IsDeployed)
        {
            return _applicationPath;
        }

        // copying, installation steps (takes some time) and assign _applicationPath

        return _applicationPath;
    }
}
```